# React native components 50% faster

Tags: javascript, react-native, text, components, createelement

I was reading these posts on Twitter, where they say that it is possible to speed up components by 50%.

Link: https://twitter.com/natebirdman/status/1695511232298783079

[image]

Link: https://twitter.com/FernandoTheRojo/status/1707762822015267219

[image]

What do you think, is it possible?

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

First "trick" looks falsy. Even if it's gonna work a little bit faster in development mode (I doubt it), it still doesn't matter for production builds.

Second one feels more realistic, but anyway should be tested with performance tool in order to understand which approach fits better with your requirements.